# How to set web-mode-content-type for react js files, using minibuffer

Tags: javascript, emacs, reactjs

I have this configuration to enable `web-mode` for `.jsx` files.

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx$" . web-mode))`

However this fails when I have `.js` extension for react files. `web-mode` can't associate content type as `jsx`.

It says:

> The var `web-mode-content-types-alist` can be used to associate a file path with a content type

But I don't want to specify a file path.

I want to associate content type using minibuffer or better auto detection.

Comment: just a sidenote: there is a emacs site in the stackexchange network: http://emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: stackexchange should put the question on emacs site when it is tagged `emacs`

Comment: @facebook, not necessarily. There is nothing wrong with asking about programming-related Emacs issues on SO. In my opinion this question is perfectly fine here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking for. Are you expecting Emacs to load a `.js` file and intelligently decide whether to use `web-mode` or `js-mode` (or some other JavaScript mode)? What would distinguish the files in these two situations?

Comment: If the extension is `jsx` web-mode associates content type to jsx but I want `js` extensions to associate content type to jsx. If it can't do it intelligently I am looking for doing it with a minibuffer command @Chris

Comment: I'm still unclear. Have you tried using `auto-mode-alist` like you did with `.jsx`? Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @Chris there is no such command, I mean I press `M-x` and type a command to execute that's minibuffer right?

Comment: @facebook, there is no such command as what? What are you trying to run via `M-x`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81452/discussion-between-facebook-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`(setq web-mode-content-types-alist '(("jsx"  . "/some/react/path/*\\.js[x]?\\'")))`

or, if you wan't to detect jsx for every js files

`(setq web-mode-content-types-alist '(("jsx"  . "\\.js[x]?\\'")))`

Comment: I am asking how to do this in `minibuffer` that is `M-x` an type command on an open emacs instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use eval-expression ( bound usually to M-: ) and then yank or type the following expression:

```
(setq web-mode-content-types-alist '(("jsx"  . "\\.js[x]?\\'")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixed in the latest version. This sets the content type interactively:

`(web-mode-set-content-type "jsx")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setting for react jsx with support web-mode.

```
(require 'jsx-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . jsx-mode))
(autoload 'jsx-mode "jsx-mode" "JSX mode" t)

(custom-set-variables
 '(jsx-indent-level 2)
 '(jsx-cmd-options '("--add-search-path" "/path/to/search-path")))

;; add web mode indent for react jsx
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . web-mode))
```